# Prevent VSCode Turn Vuejs code to vertically when onsave

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

My VSCode **onSave**

... turns my Vuejs codes vertically somehow to so many lines.
I know that it is easier to read, but I also find it very long to read, and it makes my file too long and I had to scroll down for no reason.

[image]

Is this sth that caused by **Prettier**?

Can someone pls show me how to prevent it from happening?

**settings.json**

```
"[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,  
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier formats lines to fit within the character limit of `printWidth` (default is 80 characters).

Set [`printWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) to a high value to avoid this line wrapping:

```js
// .prettierrc
{
  "printWidth": 300
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Prettier format the code like this because it's easier to read it. If you want to disable this, just change to false the *editor.formatOnSave*